# Mac environment variables not available to java runtime class

Tags: java, macos, terminal, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

Within java, I am trying to access two environment variables that I previously set on my Mac computer (running Yosemite).   I have set values for two variables:   JAVA_HOME and R_HOME.   When setting R_HOME, I did it by editing:  ~/Library/launchagents/environment.plist.

Using Terminal on the mac, I can use the 'printenv' command and get values for both variables.

When I run my java application within Eclipse, I can get the JAVA_HOME value by using:

```
System.out.println("javahome: " + System.getProperty("java.home") );
```

I have used the following code to list environment variables available to my java application (the list of available values that this code outputs includes neither JAVA_HOME nor R_HOME):

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

My application will need to be standalone, so setting environment variables within the Eclipse Run configuration won't be helpful.  Furthermore, my application won't know the value of R_HOME when it runs; the value must already be set so the application can access it at runtime and use the value to start an executable file, as in:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("$R_HOME/library/Rserve/libs/Rserve");
Process p = pb.start();
```

So, my question is:   how can my java application access the value of the R_HOME environment variable.  Either I need a new way to setting the variable so that it is available to the JVM or I need a new java method to call to access the value.

Comment: Have you tried to set the variable when starting your Java application? `java -jar app.jar -Dr.home=$R_HOME`

Comment: @andy.  Thanks for considering this question.  The scenario is that multiple users will go through the process of installing R, setting R_HOME and then downloading and installing the java application.  The java application will itself be started by an existing java application on the user's machine.   The java application I am building will require that the user will have already set R_HOME prior to running it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Java Options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI) **-D*property=value*** for setting a system property value.

`java -DR_HOME=<the-location> -jar application.jar`

Comment: thanks.  For my situation, the program that makes the call to execute the java application won't know the path unless it itself could access the value of R_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that with

```
System.getProperty("java.home")
```

you're not reading $JAVA_HOME, it just prints the Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE), see
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

My guess is be that the env-Variables are not correctly set to be accessible in your class

Comment: Yes, I see that you are exactly right regarding the System.getProperty().  Thanks.